# Are quaternions generally multiplied in an order opposite to matrices?

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, matrix-multiplication, quaternions

I was reading Jason Gregory's "Game Engine Architecture". Since he uses row vectors, there's an example that goes

> `v' = v*R1*R2*R3`

Rn being matrices. Instead, since I'm using column vectors, I would write `v' = R3*R2*R1*v`.
He then proceeds

> `v' = q3*q2*q1*v*~q1*~q2*~q3` Notice how the quaternion product must be performed in an order opposite to that in which the rotations are applied

Does that mean that I should compute `q1*q2*q3*v*~q3*~q2*~q1` instead?
Also, is the quaternion product associative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the quaternion product associative?

The `*` operator is also called [Hamilton product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Using_quaternions_as_rotations) and [it is associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Algebraic_properties).

> Does that mean that I should compute `q1*q2*q3*v*~q3*~q2*~q1` instead?

No. You are interested in applying first rotation 1, then 2, and finally 3, right? So, for the sake of clarity, you can think of your operation as `q3*(q2*(q1*v*~q1)*~q2)*~q3`. Considering that [Hamilton product is not commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Hamilton_product) you should keep that order.

Note that I used parentheses thinking that it would help interpret the equation easier. Since Hamilton product is associative, rearranging the parentheses will not change the result.